# Flatmap in java: is the lambda really necessary?

Tags: java, flatmap

Here is a code sample (form Mykong.com):

```
String[][] data = new String[][]{{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d"}, {"e", "f"}};

//Stream<String[]>
Stream<String[]> temp = Arrays.stream(data);

//Stream<String>, GOOD!
Stream<String> stringStream = temp.flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x));
```

If I understand it correctly, the lambda here is doing the actual flattening but could not flatMap understand what needs to do the flattening so that the lambda could be ommitted?

EDIT: Could flatMap have a default lambda used to convert in the "intuitive" way?

Comment: flatmap is flattening the stream of String arrays

Comment: No, it couldn't. It's obvious to you, because this specific Stream is a Stream of String[], and you can't imagine any other way to convert it to a Stream. But maybe someone would want to convert it by starting from the end of the array rather than the beginning. And what if it was a Stream<Car>? How would a flatMap() method without argument transform a Car into a Stream? All the Stream knows about its elements is that they are Objects.

Comment: `lambda here is doing the actual flattening` no, lamda here converts array to stream

Comment: @JBNizet: how can a stream of objects that are not arrays/lists be flattened by flatMap? will flatMap accept something other than an array of arrays or array of lists or lists of lists, etc.?

Comment: Of course: `streamOfCars.flatMap(car -> car.getPassengers().stream())`

Comment: @releseabe Languages like Scala do what you want, and they call this `flatten`, which is to reduce the dimensionality of a two-dimensional or higher structure by one dimension by collecting all elements together. But in Java, and C# (`SelectMany`) you need to spell it out as to 'how' the dimensional reduction needs to be effected, so you need to provide a projection (map) for the flattening function. This projection can be a lambda, an explicit method, or method group syntax (SephB). Flatmap addresses the general case - what if you wanted a filter, or ordering to happen during the flattening.

Comment: @JBNizet: okay, so flatMap needs to be told how to derive a stream from the individual instances. But do you agree that a default flattening makes sense?

Comment: @StuartLC: so Java could at some point add an argument-less flatMap, no?

Comment: ... and call it .flatten(). Yes.

Comment: No, I don't agree. Stream's generic type has no bound. It can contain anything. So it can't possibly guess how to convert these elements to a Stream, at least not in a type-safe way. And in 99.9% of the cases, what is contains is objects, not collections. So flatMap() would be inapplicable most of the time, and unsafe 100% of the time.

Comment: @JBNizet: Okay -- every example I have looked at in trying to learn about flatMap using collections -- i think a post not using collections would be valuable. Is the big deal about flatMap not the conversion to stream but the concatenation of streams into a stream?

Comment: The **two** examples in the javadoc of flatMap() don't use a collection as value of the stream: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-.

Answer (score 1):

The lambda is not required, you can accomplish the same thing via a method reference. In practice the two approaches are identical though.

The last line could be:

```
Stream<String> stringStream = temp.flatMap(Arrays::stream);
```

Comment: okay, but some instruction seems to be needed for flatMap to work. I am not sure I understand JB Nizet's comment about Stream<Car> since I thought flatMap worked on lists of lists etc. -- how can Cars be flattened although arrays/lists of cars could be.

Comment: Take it step by step: Line 1 you have an array of string arrays. Line 2 gives you a stream of string arrays. Line 3 finally gets it all unpacked turning the stream of string arrays into a stream of strings. There are 3 unpackings from String[][] -> String[] -> String.